# Por que o efeito da animação sumiu

Tags: html, css

Estou fazendo um sidNav lateral, consegui animar ele porém o efeito que a animação faz some, quando a animação acaba, queria saber o por que disso está acontecendo

Meu código

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sid nav</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contato</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Sobre</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Meu css

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}
.nav{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateX(-300px);
    z-index: 1;
    animation: animaSidNav 1s 1;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .4);
}
.nav li
{
    border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
}
.nav li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
}

@keyframes animaSidNav{
    100%{
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basta adicionar `forwards` para o `animation`, assim: `animation: animaSidNav 1s 1 forwards;`

A propriedade é "implícita", se necessitar ajustar somente o `forwards` conforme aplicar outras "classes" (seletores) para sobreescrever, mas não desejar reescrever tudo use então:

```
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

Exemplo:

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}
.nav{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateX(-300px);
    z-index: 1;
    animation: animaSidNav 1s 1 forwards;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .4);
}
.nav li
{
    border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
}
.nav li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
}

@keyframes animaSidNav{
    100%{
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
```

```html
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contato</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Sobre</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

---

Os valores possiveis são:

```
animation-fill-mode: none; /*padrão*/
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-fill-mode: backwards;
animation-fill-mode: both;
```

Se tiver múltiplas animações você pode ajustar:

```
animation-fill-mode: none, backwards;
animation-fill-mode: both, forwards, none;
```

E você pode combinar com `animation-direction` (ou `animation-iteration-count`) para ajustar direções e iterações na animação.

---

Leia mais em:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count